# campo duplicado en los registros de la consulta con Entity Framework sobre tabla sin clave principal

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework, oracle-11g

Actualmente tengo la necesidad de conectar una aplicación a una tabla de una base de datos (Oracle 11g) de otro software. Esta tabla no tiene llave primaria definida.

[image: vista de la tabla sin llave principal]

Mi Entidad es esta.

```
public partial class Inacc {
    [Key, Column("ACCHIS", Order = 1)]        
    public int Historia { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("ACCNUM", Order = 2)]
    public int Numero { get; set; } 

    [Key, Column("ACCACC", Order = 3)]
    public int Accidente { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCFUO")]
    public string Fuente { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCDOO")]
    public int? Documento { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCFEC")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCIND")]
    public string Indice { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCEAD")]
    public string Sede { get; set; }

}
```

Realizo una busqueda por HISTORIA en mi repositorio de esta forma

```
DbContext _connection = new DbContext();
DbSet<Inacc>  _dbSet = _connection.Set<Inacc>();
var inaccs = _dbSet.Where(m => m.Historia == 4353087).ToList();
```

El problema es que el resultado repite los campos FUENTE y DOCUMENTO en cada uno de los registros

[image: Imagen con resultado en javascript]

NOTA:

1. Ya he realizado este tipo de interacciones con otras tablas y me a
   funcionado correctamente.
2. No puedo modificar la tabla y agregarle una clave principal.

Comment: Los registros se corresponden con los de la base de datos? Deberías dejar un ejemplo del resultado que esperas.. sino es muy difícil ayudarte!

Comment: Si, los registros se corresponden, los nombres de los campos son los que están en la anotación Column de la entidad.
En la primera imagen esta el resultado que espero que salga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una forma de solucionarlo y fue crear un repositorio aparte con las consultas directas en sql (rellenando con un CASE los campos nulos de Documento y Fuente con cero con `DbSqlQuery`, 
adicione en mi repositorio principal esta función

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetWihtRawSql(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        object[] parameter = GenerateParameters(parameters);
        return _dbSet.SqlQuery(query, parameter).ToList();
    }
```

y mi repositorio

```
    public class InaccRepository : CrosamRepository<Inacc>
    {
        public InaccRepository(CrosamConnection _connection, DefaultConnection context) : base(_connection, context)
        {

        }

        public IEnumerable<Inacc> GetAccidentes(int historia)
        {
            string sql = "select ACCHIS As Historia,  ACCNUM As Numero,  CASE  WHEN ACCFUO IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE ACCFUO END As Fuente," +
                "CASE  WHEN ACCDOO IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ACCDOO END  As Documento,  " +
                "ACCACC As Accidente,  ACCFEC As Fecha,  ACCIND As Indice,  ACCEAD As Sede  " +
                "from INACC where ACCHIS = :historia";
            return GetWihtRawSql(sql, 
                new OracleParameter("historia", historia));
        }

        public IEnumerable<Inacc> GetAccidenteByHc(int his, int num, int acc)
        {
            string sql = "select ACCHIS As Historia,  ACCNUM As Numero,  CASE  WHEN ACCFUO IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE ACCFUO END As Fuente," +
                "CASE  WHEN ACCDOO IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ACCDOO END  As Documento,  " +
                "ACCACC As Accidente,  ACCFEC As Fecha,  ACCIND As Indice,  ACCEAD As Sede  " +
                "from INACC where ACCHIS = :historia and ACCNUM = :num and ACCACC = :acc";
            return GetWihtRawSql(sql,
                new OracleParameter("historia", his),
                new OracleParameter("num", num),
                new OracleParameter("acc", acc));
        }

        public IEnumerable<Inacc> GetAccidenteByExt(string fue, int doc, string sed)
        {
            string sql = "select ACCHIS As Historia,  ACCNUM As Numero,  CASE  WHEN ACCFUO IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE ACCFUO END As Fuente," +
                "CASE  WHEN ACCDOO IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ACCDOO END  As Documento,  " +
                "ACCACC As Accidente,  ACCFEC As Fecha,  ACCIND As Indice,  ACCEAD As Sede  " +
                "from INACC where ACCFUO = :fue and ACCDOO = :doc and ACCEAD = :sed";
            return GetWihtRawSql(sql,
                new OracleParameter("fue", fue),
                new OracleParameter("doc", doc),
                new OracleParameter("sed", sed));
        }
    }
```

por último modifique mi entidad los campos Documento y fuente agregándolos como llave primaria

```
    public partial class Inacc {

    [Key, Column("ACCHIS", Order = 1)]        
    public int Historia { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("ACCNUM", Order = 2)]
    public int Numero { get; set; } 

    [Key, Column("ACCACC", Order = 3)]
    public int Accidente { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("ACCFUO", Order = 5)]
    public string Fuente { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("ACCDOO", Order = 4)]
    public int Documento { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCFEC")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCIND")]
    public string Indice { get; set; }

    [Column("ACCEAD")]
    public string Sede { get; set; }

}
```